# storing sensitive information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, certificate

I am not sure what I am asking for so please bear with me.

how can I implement in ruby scenario like this:

user have some kind of sensitive information, e.g. `{ token: "blabla", email: "blabal@blabal.com"}`
now, the user should use some kind of procedure to encrypt the data and upload them to the server/database.

now, the web application should use the information to connect to another app and should be able to decrypt the data in order to use them, so probably the app need to have some kind of second key to decrypt the info.

i dont know if I am clear on this, please ask any question. Thank you for any suggestion and information.

I am expeting code/hints/aditional information/tools to use in order to solve my problem.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [Active Record Encryption in the official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html).

Comment: So the user encrypts the data and the web application decrypts it? That's what HTTPS already does. Can you explain the whole process a little more detailed? Which app is supposed to see the (decrypted) data and which app must not see it?

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt different approaches. For example this might be helpful.
In this way, you can set a token/key to application level, something like private key. That will be using for encryption and decryption.

```
token = ActiveRecord::Encryption.encryptor.encrypt('something here to encrypt as a salt, etc.')
Base64.encode64(ActiveRecord::Encryption.encryptor.encrypt("#{token}@YOUCANPUTMORESTRONGKEYHERE@#{email-or-token-or-what-ever}"))
```

**For decryption**

```
decoded_token = ActiveRecord::Encryption.encryptor.decrypt(
    Base64.decode64(params[:token])
  )

  encoded_token, email_or_token = decoded_token.split('@TOKEN@')
```